# Spring IllegalStateException: bean of type WebApplication not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, wicket

i am doing a web application with spring and tomcat. When i run the app, i get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter wicket.filter
java.lang.IllegalStateException: bean of type [org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication] not found
    at org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory.createApplication(SpringWebApplicationFactory.java:160)
    at org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory.createApplication(SpringWebApplicationFactory.java:139)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:308)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:286)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4746)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5399)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 version="3.0">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>       
            classpath:*/META-INF/persistence-context.xml,
            classpath:*/META-INF/service-context.xml,
            classpath:*/META-INF/web-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>configuration</param-name>
        <param-value>development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>wicket.filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationFactoryClassName</param-name>
            <param-value>org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>wicket.filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>7200</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

And that is not all. In my web-context.xml a bean can´t be found and it is created in service-context.xml

Comment: You don't mention Wicket at all in your question, yet your problem seems to be missing Wicket classes. Are you trying to combine Wicket with Spring or was this an accident?

Comment: You could also add the relevant Spring configuration in the question. It seems it is missing the required Wicket beans.

Comment: Oh yea, i forgott wicket. Yes i am using it.